# self-type does not conform error with play2reactivemongo

Tags: playframework, reactivemongo

I met the following error after upgrading play2reactivemongo to 0.11.0.play24. The code compiles fine before the upgrade.

Code:

```
object TestController extends Controller with MongoController with CookieLang{
```

Error Message:

```
self-type controllers.TestController.type does not conform to play.modules.reactivemongo.MongoController's selftype play.modules.reactivemongo.MongoController with play.api.mvc.Controller with play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoComponents
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as Play 2.4 introduces the new dependency injection, your Mongo controller must `extends MongoController with ReactiveMongoComponents` (play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoComponents).

The new trait indicates at compile time that your controller must be provided a `reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi` (play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi).

Then if you want to inject automatically this `reactiveMongoApi`, you will have to follow the steps indicated in the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11.0/documentation/tutorial/play2.html#play-24).